# Do atoms exist, or are they just fable?

Tags: physics

A self-published religious tract [Χξς](https://www.edocr.com/v/w6xgg6db) by Wayne Ellis Pyron Jr. contains a number of extraordinary claims.

On the first page he claims to be Buddha and also the god of the Old Testament.

On the second he claims (in a writing style that continues throughout the book):

> ATOMS DON'T EXIST AT ALL, RATHER JUST LIKE ALL THINGS OF THE EARTH, ALL OF WHAT EARTH CALLS "PHYSICS" IS JUST TELLING FABLES THAT ARE JUST LIES.

I started to do some Google searching and tried to find a photo of an atom, but each photo seemed like a cartoon or 3d drawing more than a real photo.

Do atoms exist?

Comment: The OP's rhetoric and phrasing, combined with the link, make me wonder whether this is just an advertisement for the book disguised as a question, and not actually a genuine question.

Comment: @logs22 are you the author?

Comment: Lots of off-topic discussion deleted. This is not a site for discussing your faith-based views; it is a site for empirical evidence.  Do NOT engage with others on this in the comments; flag the comments for deletion.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) This question is a duplicate. If it wasn't a duplicate it would be closed for lack of notability - one man posting a long religious screed is not evidence that this is widely believed.

Answer (score 7):

**No, atoms are quite real.**

The linked book does not seem coherent nor make any testable claims. Instead lets see about the evidence for atoms.

First direct observation of atoms was done by Rutherford in the famous scattering experiment: [Rutherford scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering).

> tried to find a photo of an atom, but each photo seemed like a cartoon or 3d drawing more than a real photo

Yes, this is true. There are no photos of atoms. Reason for this is that atoms are approximately on the scale of 1Å = 10^-10m. [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius). Photographs use visible light, which wavelength is around 10^-7m. You can't really use larger 'objects' to examine smaller than they are. (Gross simplification here.)

But there's more. Electromagnetic spectrum is not limited. We can use smaller wavelength to gain resolution. In case of molecules this technique is called [X-ray scattering.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_scattering_techniques).

Yet, we are not limited to atoms, but there are techniques to 'peek inside' the atoms. [NMR spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance_spectroscopy), for instance.

Comment: I'll ask you the same question that I asked Shadur, if all those who told you "atoms exist" were lying to you, would you still be sure atoms exist? what evidence would you present in that scenario that they still exist?

Comment: @logs22 Because chemistry as is wouldn't work without atoms, nor electronics (like the device you're using to post here), nor medical scans, X-rays, advanced metallurgy, materials science.... the list built the technology around you. Unless you believe in simulation theory or a vast conspiracy to fool you into not believing in some or other "One True God". The book seems no more than an emotional rant with no basis in fact.

Comment: @logs22 I'm quite sure. I don't need to rely on word of people: I've personally performed x-ray scattering as part of my physics studies. Additionally I've done development of  NMR measurements as part of my PhD work.

Comment: After reading the comments, I no longer believe the question was asked in good faith.

Comment: @pinegulf OP is clearly the author, lol

Comment: You could add atomic force pictures ;)

Comment: OP: Imagine that chemist's were able to draw structures as complicated as those of sugars or even chlorophyll-like molecules...before of any technique able to give the images/insights mentioned above.